# Why does my data accumulate between object instances?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but why does the code below output:

```
[1, 'mysql']
['dbc has been deleted']
[1, 'mysql', 1, 'sqlite']
```

instead of:

```
[1, 'mysql']
['dbc has been deleted']
[1, 'sqlite']
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mysql.connector as mysql
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import os
import sys


class DBAdapter (object):
    config = {
        'database': None,
    }
    data = []

    _conn = None
    _cur = None
    _sql = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._state = [[_k, self.config.update({_k: _v})] for _k, _v in kwargs.items()]

    def __enter__(self):
        self.connect()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.data = []
        if len(args) == 3 and args[2] is not None:
            log(args)
        self.close()

    def connect(self):
        pass

    def init_cursor(self):
        self._cur = self._conn.cursor()
        return self._cur

    def execute(self, query, args=[]):
        self.init_cursor()
        self._sql = query
        return self._cur.execute(query, args)

    def fetchall(self, query, args=()):
        self.execute(query, args)
        self.data.append(self._cur.fetchall())
        return self._cur.close()

    def close(self):
        self._conn.close()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MySQLAdapter (DBAdapter):
    config = {
        'user': os.environ['USER'],
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database': 'mysql',
        'raise_on_warnings': True,
        'option_groups': 'autodba',
        'option_files': [
            os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.mysql', 'development.cnf'),
        ]
    }

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self._conn = mysql.connect(**self.config)
        except (mysql.errors.InterfaceError, mysql.errors.ProgrammingError):
            log('Failed to connect', sys.exc_info())


class SQLiteAdapter (DBAdapter):
    config = {
        'database': 'analyze.db',
    }

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self._conn = sqlite.connect(self.config.get('database', ':memory:'))
        except (sqlite.InterfaceError, sqlite.ProgrammingError):
            log('Failed to connect', sys.exc_info())


def log(*args):
    flatten = lambda *msg: (sub for part in msg for sub in (
        flatten(*part) if isinstance(part, (tuple, list)) else (part,)))
    sys.stderr.write(u'{0}\n'.format(list(flatten(args))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MySQLAdapter(host='127.0.0.1', database='test') as dbc:
        try:
            dbc.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE testing')
            dbc.execute('INSERT INTO testing (data) VALUES (%s)', args=[('mysql')])
            dbc.fetchall('SELECT id, data FROM testing LIMIT 1')
            log(dbc.data)
        except mysql.errors.ProgrammingError:
            log('MySQL query failed', sys.exc_info())

    try:
        del dbc
        log(type(dbc))
    except NameError:
        log('dbc has been deleted')

    with SQLiteAdapter(database='test.db') as dbc:
        try:
            dbc.execute('DELETE FROM testing')
            dbc.execute('INSERT INTO testing (data) VALUES (?)', args=[('sqlite')])
            dbc.fetchall('SELECT rowid, data FROM testing LIMIT 1')
            log(dbc.data)
        except sqlite.ProgrammingError:
            log('SQLite query failed', sys.exc_info())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're mutating `DBAdapter.data`, which is referred to by all the classes and instances. If that's not what you want (it's not), you should put `self.data = []` in the `DBAdapter.__init__()` method instead of defining `DBAdapter.data` as a class attribute. That way, each instance will have it's own `data` attribute.

Comment: OK, so why does `self.data` appear empty during the `__exit__` method?

Comment: What do you mean it appears empty? In `__exit__()`, you're assigning a new, empty list to that instance's `data` attribute. The original list is still in memory, being pointed to by everything else.

Comment: Thanks, that's explained my mistake - `del` wasn't clearing the reference as expected... but, I will make use of this behaviour for easy access to results from another data source.

Comment: @Cez, ehh.. I would be very careful about using that behaviour. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: If it's using shared memory space and I want to store data from a in b (and be careful doing so) then it will reduce the overhead, or am I wrong there?

Comment: That's too vague for me to answer :P. Perhaps you should ask a new question about that, with details about what you're thinking of doing. Feel free to post a link to it here.